# Is ther any way to use GTFSRealtime with a WIndows 10 Universal app?

Tags: windows-10-universal

There are Google libraries to read/parse GTFSRealtime data for c# but they are not usable for windows 10 Universal apps. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Sorry, the basic question is how to read a GTFSRealtime stream in a Windows Universal app - I was just trying to give an overview of what I have already tried. Should I re-ask the question in a different way?

Comment: Your question as written is asking us to recommend alternative libraries, which the quote from the help center (*recommend or find a...software library*) clearly says is off-topic here. I can't suggest a way for you to rephrase it, because you're either asking for that recommendation or you're asking something else entirely, and I don't know what that *something else* would be.